# EC2 AWS Instance not building bcrypt dependency

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, node.js, bcrypt

I'm posting this here as it's clearly a server configuration issue rather than a code issue.

I've got an application working on my local Windows PC, however when trying to run:

`npm install bcrypt`

on an AWS EC2 server (RHEL), I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.2 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
```

There do appear to be a number of posts about bcrypt node module not working in certain environments, but none appear to be on a RHEL EC2 box, except one which told me to run the following (which didn't work):

```
sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
sudo yum groupinstall "Development tools"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing my dependency from `bcrypt` to `bcryptjs`. I'd like to know why this worked...but alas.

Comment: Alas, you buried your question in an answer so no one will be able give you an answer.

Comment: @chicks On the contrary. Changing the dependency 'fixed it' and therefore is *an* answer, however, I've left it open for other more verbose answers. Alternatively, people could comment on this answer.

Comment: Commenting for people of the future, you've replaced a C++ implementation of bcrypt with a pure JS one which might not be an answer for everyone (it's ~~30% slower). The error you got from npm's attempt to build it would have been above the error in the OP. Interestingly it also doesn't answer the question as phrased...

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer in this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60758413/4638376

I had to install the native components:

```
sudo yum install -y gcc-c++
```